# Calling event emitter inside promise in Angular 2

Tags: events, angular, typescript, promise, eventemitter

I can't get my event emitter to function properly inside a promise's then method. I'm not getting any errors. It just simply won't call

in the child component, :

```
@Output() isLoggingIn = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

onLogin() {
  this.isLoggingIn.emit(true); //<-- this gets called, so it works.
  this.authService.loginUser(this.loginForm.value)
    .then( () => { 
      console.log(this.isLoggingIn.emit); //<-- This logs out the method.
      this.isLoggingIn.emit(false); //<-- This doesn't get called!
    })
    .catch( (err) => console.log(err) );
}
```

This is the parent component's HTML template, header.component.html:

```
<tas-loginform
  (isLoggingIn)="setLoginLoading($event)"
  *ngIf="!isSigningUp">
</tas-loginform>
```

This is the parent component's typescript code, header.component.ts:

```
setLoginLoading(bool: boolean) {
  console.log(bool);
  this.loginLoading = bool;
}
```

It's almost as if the Event Emitter call in the promise's .then callback is never getting called at all since it doesn't run the setLoginLoading's console.log. And it makes it even harder because there are no error messages at all.

Comment: Are you sure that `this` inside the `.then()` handler is referring to the object you want it to? I remember that being a tricky issue the last time I worked in JS.

Comment: I am sure. I made a plunkr, trying to replicate the issue. But the plunkr actually works, while my code doesn't. I guess there might be something else going on... http://embed.plnkr.co/l50UlTSAh3p102lG5Db9/

Comment: Maybe the order you load zone and polyfills?

Comment: It's all set to default. I ended up getting it working anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with how routing was somehow messing up my authentication state. I really can't explain it. I took out routing in my project and somehow everything works great.